# junit5 with selenium testcontainer not working

Tags: selenium, junit5, testcontainers

Goal - I want to be able to write selenium tests, using [Junit 5](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/), and [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/). I am writing a very simple code to just be able to check an attribute of the search bar of google's homepage.

Issue - chrome.getWebDriver(); returns null. Am I missing something?

**exception - java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.manage()" because "driver" is null.**

this is caused as I try to set an implicit wait after initializing WebDriver.

---

my pom.xml -

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
    <test-containers.version>1.16.0</test-containers.version>
    <selenium.version>3.141.59</selenium.version>
    <junit.version>5.8.1</junit.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
        <version>${test-containers.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium</artifactId>
        <version>${test-containers.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>${test-containers.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

---

My test class -

```
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@Testcontainers
public class GoogleTest {

    @Container
    public BrowserWebDriverContainer<?> chrome = new BrowserWebDriverContainer<>()
            .withCapabilities(Config.getChromeOptions());

    private GooglePage googlePage;

    @BeforeAll
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        // ISSUE IS WITH THE LINE BELOW
        WebDriver driver = chrome.getWebDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(7, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        // trying to use page object model, just navigates to the google homepage
        googlePage = new GooglePage(driver);
    }

    @Test
    public void testTitle() throws Exception {
        WebElement element = googlePage.getSearchBar();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        assertEquals(element.getAttribute("role"), "combobox");
    }

}
```

*[In case you need it, the google drive link for the code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15Blts1Ek-ShF3gzXZ9mwzp9BRHJ6wHPb/view?usp=sharing)*

Comment: Missing `.withCapabilities(new ChromeOptions())` ?

Comment: no, like I was setting headless=true there, so i removed it from the snippet here for brevity. thanks though

Answer (score 1):

got my mistake, if using junit5, [fields should be private static](https://www.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/junit_5/#:%7E:text=private%20static%20final) final I think...

I was still using [public](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/webdriver_containers/#:%7E:text=The%20following%20field%20in%20your%20JUnit%20UI%20test%20class%20will%20prepare%20a%20container%20running%20Chrome%3A)...